# How can i limit the amount of pages shown in pagination

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, logic

I am building a pagination component using React and after i used it i realised that it was showing all the pages and as a result expanded the entire page so that you have to scroll accross to view the rest of the pages. How can i limit it only to 20 pages and allow the number of pages to go up each time without taking up space?

The furthest i got to logic was this.

**if (numberOfPages > 20 ) {
             return 
        }**

numberOfPages returns the total amount of pages.

I am not sure on what method to use for a task like this.

Here is my code.

````
const Pagination = ({ numberOfPages, page, setPage }: any) => {
  const pageNumbers = (numberOfPages: number) => {
    let pages = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
      pages.push(
        <span
          key={i}
          onClick={e => setPage(i)}
          className={page === i ? "active" : ""}
        >
          {i}
        </span>
      );
        // if (numberOfPages > 20 ) {
        //      return 
        // }
    }
    return pages;
  };

  return (
    <div className="pagination">
      <div className="page-numbers">
        <span
          onClick={e => (page === 1 ? {} : setPage(page - 1))}
          className={page === 1 ? "disabled" : ""}
        >
          &laquo;
        </span>
        {pageNumbers(numberOfPages)}
        <span
          onClick={e => (page === numberOfPages ? {} : setPage(page + 1))}
          className={page === numberOfPages ? "disabled" : ""}
        >
          &raquo;
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pagination; ```
````

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). [See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate

I don't have the answer to your question, but here's a npm package which does the pagination by itself

Comment: Thank you. Trying to avoid packages as i have used too many. Trying to see if i could utilise Math.ceil . Still struggling so far

Answer (score 0):

It is not really React, but I believe you can extract the logic. I just implemented something similar to what you need recently.

Notice: pageIndex is the currentPageIndex, and starts with 0. Pages returned in array starts with 1, for better user experience.

```
const getLastPageIndex = function (totalNumberOfItems, pageSize) {
    return Math.floor((totalNumberOfItems + pageSize - 1) / pageSize) - 1;
}

const getPageIndexOptions = function (totalNumberOfItems, maxNumberOfOptions, pageSize, pageIndex) {
    const options = [];
    const pivot = Math.ceil(maxNumberOfOptions/2);
    const lastPageIndex = getLastPageIndex(totalNumberOfItems, pageSize);

    if (lastPageIndex <= maxNumberOfOptions) {

      while(options.length < lastPageIndex) options.push(options.length + 1);
    } else if (pageIndex < pivot) {

      while(options.length < maxNumberOfOptions) options.push(options.length + 1);
    } else if (pageIndex > (lastPageIndex - pivot)) {

      while(options.length < maxNumberOfOptions) options.unshift(lastPageIndex - options.length + 1);
    } else {

      for (var i = pageIndex - (pivot - 1); options.length < maxNumberOfOptions; i++) {
        options.push(i + 1);
      }
    }

    return options;
}

getPageIndexOptions(100, 5, 15, 0) // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
getPageIndexOptions (100, 5, 15, 4) // returns [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```